# Am I using and Android in-memory way to share data that's simply not the way the Android activity model works?

Tags: android, multithreading

I've asked various questions related to one goal: ***how to develop an Android app that plots bluetooth data forever in real-time***. I now have a new question from a different angle. To be fair to new readers I will cover some of the same background, but basically the question is in the title.

I found some open source code [Bluetooth](http://pymasde.es/blueterm/) that apparently creates a background thread which updates the screen with new data it receives over a bluetooth connection. Then when I launch my Plot activity I can see the bluetooth background thread continue to write bluetooth data to Logcat. **So I know for a fact the bluetooth background thread is still running when I launch my Plot activity.**

Again, my goal is to plot the bluetooth data that is continually provided by the bluetooth background thread. **I have succeeded as follows**: since this bluetooth background thread seems to run continually and just won't die, *I decided to use its update() method to call my static Plot.plotData() method to plot the data*. **And this works**. It will will run endlessly with out a problem - receiving bluetooth data and plotting it via periodic calls from the bluetooth background method update() to my static Plot.plotData() method.

Although I have received some negative feedback regarding my solution, I have found [sharing data across Activities](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/b8e42d402b6319db?pli=1) where Edward Falk says sharing static data is OK. Here Edward Falk asks: "Are the activities all in the same application? [yes]  Same task? [not sure] It seems to me that you could just store the data in a static variable accessible by all of the activities." Well I tried static data and it worked, but I switched to a static method Plot.plotData() which seems to work better for me.

The latest feedback I have received from one person @emmby that says my static Plot.plotData() *goes against the following*: **"It sounds like you're looking for an in-memory way to share data, and that's simply not the way the Android activity model works."** But what am I else to do? I thought that an Android phone has a limited amount of RAM for running Activities (one at a time), threads, handlers, Services, AnycTasks, etc. And an SD card for persisting data.

@emmby seem to say that in order to share data from a bluetooth background thread to my Plot activity (Plot.plotData()) that I must use the SD card. This doesn't sound right. After all I have it working using my static method Plot.plotData().

Frankly I don't see anything wrong with my solution primary because those who criticize it do not follow up with a definitive alternative.

If you find my solution deficient please speak up and provide a definitive solution. Otherwise I will take Edward Faulk's solution as the best one.

Comment: If it works, it works.  That said, you may have to worry about the GC cleaning up your Bluetooth receiver class and, in the processes, wiping out your static variable.  I have seen some other questions on SO with issues with their static fields being GCed but you may have references to an instance of your listener class somewhere, keeping it safe.

Comment: "Frankly I don't see anything wrong with my solution primary because those who criticize it do not follow up with a definitive alternative." A dangerous philosophy. No one is obliged to give you all the solutions you need.

I think CommonsWare pointed you strongly in the right direction here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237560/android-static-method-plots-background-thread-data-nicely-in-real-time-but-is-it/6237681#6237681. I agree with CommonsWare that your use of static variables is suspect, and add that updating the UI in any thread but the main thread is a no-no.

Comment: I'll also add that the fact that it works for you now and has always worked for you does not mean that it will always work for everyone, everywhere. That is *especially* true when you are knowingly breaking the rules for how to do things. If you plan to have anyone else use this app, you might want to keep this in mind.

Comment: @Dan you should have posted an answer. I would have accepted it. As for @CommonsWare he does get straight to the point, and many times I have difficulty follow him. So I often review his answers hoping it will soak into my thick head:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, your thread is running at the background **even when none of the activities** display data obtained by that thread. For example, let's consider scenario:

1. You started your bluetooth thread.
2. Your activity A started and now read data from that thread.
3. Your activity A is backgrounded (for example user navigates away via "Recent" tasks).
4. Your activity is idle but bluetooth thread still consumes cpu and power.

If you don't use your bluetooth data you shouldn't run the thread. You can introduce some kind of counter that tracks number of clients that use your thread's data. And if counter drops to zero - thread stops/pauses.

But Android has built-in solution for such cases. You can introduce service which will be bound by different activities and will have `DataSource` interface with `getNextData` function. See [Bounded Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html) for more details.

When there are no clients bound to service Android will stop the service. This way you completely decouple Activities from thread. Your bluetooth thread is now managed by Service. And Service is now managed by Android.

In your case Local Service should be enough to share data between your thread and activities.

Comment: @inazaruck I must make it clear that the thread created by my bluetooth activity never dies. It justs run forever. And continually it calls my static method Plot.plotData().

Comment: If you need it to run forever, the Local Service is still a better approach. User can see that something is working in background, and Android will not kill your process just because there are no Activities running. But in this case you need to start your service explicitly and only then bind Activities to this service.

Comment: @inazaruk, why don't you address that my bluetooth background thread never dies - it runs endlessy. I'll don't have to make any changes, it just runs forever! So you say "If you need it to run forever, the Local Service is still a better approach." But it already runs forever. So why do I need a local service?

Comment: Ok, your thread runs forever. But your activity is not. And if you don't have active activities in your process it will be killed (sooner or later). To give Android a clue that you have something that runs in background, you need to create a service. You still have your bluetooth thread, but it now logically belongs to service. Android knows you have running service in the process, so it will not kill it until absolutely necessary. Plus, you have a built-in way of communicating data from your service (read "blutooth thread") to activities.

Comment: @inazaruk thanks for the nice answer. You commented: "Ok, your thread runs forever. But your Activity is not." I think @CommonsWare refers to this as a thread leak and a bad design. I am trying to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: @inazaruk can you comment on what someone told me (I have been waiting for his comment):"It sounds like you're looking for an in-memory way to share data, and that's simply not the way the Android activity model works." Then how does the Android activity model work? I thought Android phone has limited RAM for running things and SD card for persisting data. I don't want to persist any data. I want to plot it in real-time adding newest data point and discarding oldest one.